# Download HTML Table as excel in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, export-to-excel

Cannot export HTML Table in excel if there is # in the text, Ho w can I escape #?

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>#test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the code, it is working.You can try like below;

```
<html>
<head> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>  </head>

<body>
<div>
    <table id="testTable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>#test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel"> Export to Excel</button>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working snippet :)

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: table.innerHTML
    }
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

```html
<table id="tableToExcelId" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>#test</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tableToExcelId', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```